# Add custom product status in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We sell computer parts at our woocommerce based website.
IT products become old very quickly, so I have thousands of End-Of-Life (EOL) products.
We update and check prices via REST API, so our system spend too much time for EOL products.
On the other hand, We don't want to delete or make them private because they bring big visitors from google search.
So, we think to add a custom status to product. Like EOL. So products will be listed on google but since we will update only Published status products it will not be problem.

I found below code but can't be sure it is correct. Because when I add this code and select EOL, It doesn't look as I want.
Before select EOL: https://prnt.sc/00qzWQV6saTp
After select EOL and save: https://prnt.sc/VkTzLq1S1EZP

Any advise?

```
    register_post_status( 'custom-hide-product', array(
    'label'                     => _x( 'EOL', 'post' ),
    'public'                    => true,
    'exclude_from_search'       => false,
    'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
    'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
    'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'EOL <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'EOL <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ),
) );
   
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'display_hide_status_option' );
function display_hide_status_option() {
    global $post;
    $complete = '';
    $label    = '';
    if ( $post->post_type === 'product' ) {
        if ( $post->post_status === 'custom-hide-product' ) {
            $selected = 'selected';
        }
        echo '<script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                    $("select#post_status").append("<option value=\"custom-hide-product\" ' . $complete . '>EOL</option>");
                    $(".misc-pub-section label").append("' . $label . '");
                });
              </script>
        ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$label is always empty in your code, it must be set if $post->post_status === 'custom-hide-product'.

And replace `$(".misc-pub-section label").append("' . $label . '");` with `$(".misc-pub-section #post-status-display").html("' . $label . '");` if $label is 'EOL'